# Reading multiple csv files using pyspark. Only when the data size exceeds a certain size

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Reading multiple csv files using pyspark. Only when the data size exceeds a certain size

scala code

```
val rawStocks = allStocks.filter(_.size >= 260 * 5 + 10)
```

example pyspark code

```
rawStocks = filter(lambda stock: len(stock) >= 260*5+10,readHistories(prefix + "stocks/"))
```

my code

```
stocksDir = sc.textFile("./data/stocks/")
header = stocksDir.first()
stocksDir = stocksDir.filter(lambda x : x!= header)
stocksDir.take(5)

> ['31-Dec-13,22.25,22.47,22.15,22.43,33246316', 
> '30-Dec-13,22.00,22.33,22.00,22.25,27713912', 
> '27-Dec-13,21.79,22.05,21.78,22.02,24100877', 
> '26-Dec-13,21.72,21.88,21.72,21.80,17067392',  
> '24-Dec-13,21.46,21.76,21.44,21.69,18371968']
```

I try this. but the len(fields) is count the row, not csv file size.

```
stocksDir.map(lambda x:x.split(header)).filter(lambda fields:len(fields)>0).collect()

> [['', ''],
['31.Dec.13,32.38,32.38,31.66,31.66,598'],
['16.Dec.13,31.53,31.53,31.53,31.53,363'],
['9.Dec.13,32.18,32.26,31.58,31.83,30475'],
['22.Nov.13,31.05,31.43,31.05,31.43,735'],
['', ''],
['31.Dec.13,21.31,21.76,20.8,21.11,61631'],
['21.Nov.13,19.25,19.78,19.22,19.57,55711']]


stocksDir.map(lambda x:x.split(header)).filter(lambda fields:len(fields)>5).collect()
> []
```

Comment: Can you confirm whether the first example of code, written is Scala, is doing as you expect and would like to achieve in python? Spark operations typically deal with the underlying data. You might be best of reading the file size using a python “io” package to choose the files you want to read and pass those to the spark read command.